# Output for scraped data with Text value in CSV file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, export-to-csv

I am new to web scraping using Python and need help on extracting Sub category name (Title) and the Page Title (Main Category Header) with the URLs that is being scraped with my Python code. I tried .text with beautifulsoup but I think there could be better option to do this task as I am getting error and no output once used.

Help would be appreciated. Please take a look at the code and help with Output stored in csv file with URL \t Sub category title \t Main Category header.

**Example:** [Subcategory URL](http://www.medicalexpo.com/cat/pediatrics-N.html)
Required:

```
http://www.medicalexpo.com/medical-manufacturer/neonatal-incubator-2963.html        Neonatal incubators        Pediatrics
http://www.medicalexpo.com/medical-manufacturer/infant-radiant-warmer-13522.html        
Infant radiant warmers      Pediatrics
http://www.medicalexpo.com/medical-manufacturer/infant-phototherapy-lamp-44327.html        Infant phototherapy lamps        Pediatrics
```

Something like this

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodecsv
import time
import random

def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

url = 'http://www.medicalexpo.com/'
soup = get_soup(url)
raw_categories = soup.select('div.univers-main li.category-group-item a')
print(raw_categories)
category_links = {}

for cat in (raw_categories):
    t0 = time.time()
    response_delay = time.time() - t0 
    time.sleep(10*response_delay) 
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,5)) 
    soup = get_soup(cat['href'])
    links = soup.select('#category-group li a')

    category_links[cat.links] = [link['href'] for link in links]
    print(category_links)
```